# "apt-get update" giving "W: Failed to fetch http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu/dists/scrapy/..."

Tags: apt, updates

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

I am trying to run "sudo apt-get update", but it results in Scrapy related errors. I even "purged"(uninstalled) Scrapy, but I am still getting this error.

```
.....

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US                
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu/dists/scrapy/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu/dists/scrapy/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.scrapy.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Remove it from your `sources.list` files.  It's a user-added entry so you, or another 'admin' on your system has added it, and I get 404 errors if I put it in the browser.  Just remove that line from your sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory for scrapy occurrences.
Also check this file: `/etc/apt/sources.list` and delete the line pointing to scrapy, if there is an entry.

After that, `sudo apt update` should stop showing these error messages.

Comment: There was no entry for scrapy in "/etc/apt/sources.list", but it did have files in "/etc/apt/sources.list.d" directory, removing which solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

so I did these two steps

`sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list /etc/apt/sources.list_deleted`

`sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list.save /etc/apt/sources.list_save_deleted`

`sudo apt-get update`