# WSL2 ubuntu 22.04 gnome-desktop error

Tags: package-management, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting this error.

```
Could not resolve 'wsl-translinux.arkane-systems.net'
Fetched 337 kB in 7s (47.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch https://wsl-translinux.arkane-systems.net/apt/InRelease  Could not resolve 'wsl-translinux.arkane-systems.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
./wsl2-setup-desktop-gnome.sh: line 57: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["apt-get update" giving "W: Failed to fetch http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu/dists/scrapy/..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118189/apt-get-update-giving-w-failed-to-fetch-http-archive-scrapy-org-ubuntu-dis)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a repository from [this person](https://arkane-systems.net/) which is indeed inaccessible for me also. This doesn't look like an Ubuntu specific issue, but networking, or the remote service is down.

I'd use the link above to contact the provider, and ask them. I don't think we can help, other than suggest you remove the repository from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files.